# pandas/matplotlib datetime tick labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with datetime values including microseconds:

```
                            column1    column2  
time                                                                        
1900-01-01 10:39:52.887916  19363.876  19362.7575   
1900-01-01 10:39:53.257916  19363.876  19362.7575   
1900-01-01 10:39:53.808007  19363.876  19362.7575   
1900-01-01 10:39:53.827894  19363.876  19362.7575   
1900-01-01 10:39:54.277931  19363.876  19362.7575
```

I plot the dataframe as follows:

```
def plot(df):
    ax = df.plot(y='column1', figsize=(20, 8))
    df.plot(y='column2', ax=ax)

    ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)

    mpl.pyplot.show()
```

Notice on the image below that the microseconds are displayed as `%f` rather than their actual value.

That is, instead of `10:39:52.887916` it displays `10:39:52.%f`

How can I display the actual microseconds in the tick labels (even if it's only a few significant digits)?

[image]

Comment: Did you set a DateFormatter somewhere? That looks to me like a leetle typo in the string-formatting passed to a DateFormatter. And something isn't default; when I run your code I get a completely different wrong set of xticklabels. Could be in pandas, could be in seaborn?

Comment: I didn't set it, perhaps it's in pandas. I'm not using seaborn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the major ticks to the format you want, using `set_major_formatter`:

```
In [14]:

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.dates
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1,2,3,4],
                   'column2': [2,3,4,5]},
                   index =pd.to_datetime([1e8,2e8,3e8,4e8]))
def plot(df):
    ax = df.plot(y='column1', figsize=(20, 8))
    df.plot(y='column2', ax=ax)

    ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f'))

    #mpl.pyplot.show()
    return ax

print df
                            column1  column2
1970-01-01 00:00:00.100000        1        2
1970-01-01 00:00:00.200000        2        3
1970-01-01 00:00:00.300000        3        4
1970-01-01 00:00:00.400000        4        5
```

[image]

If the problem do go away, then I think somewhere in the code the formatter format is specified incorrectly, namely `%%f` instead of `%f`, which returns a literal `'%'` character.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what is happening in my code. I've copied your excerpt and I get microseconds correctly printed. In my code I've done the exact same as you, but get the `%f` as I described! Very strange!

Comment: I replaced your `df = pd.Dataframe` call with `df = my_df` and it prints micros as `%.f`, so it's something to do with the dataframe